# Module Build Failure with Unexpected token error on npm start - react/webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, routes, webpack

I'm attempting to create my first react application, following this tutorial I found online: http://jmfurlott.com/tutorial-setting-up-a-single-page-react-web-app-with-react-router-and-webpack/.

However I've run into a problem after completing it. I keep getting this error when I do an 'npm start' in the command line:

> ERROR in ./js/app.js Module build failed: SyntaxError:
>   /Users/justinkruse/nike-plus-api/js/app.js: Unexpected token (10:6)

app.js:

```
import React from 'react';  
import Router from 'react-router';  
import { DefaultRoute, Link, Route, RouteHandler } from 'react-router';

import LoginHandler from './components/Login.js';

var App = React.createClass({  
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="nav"> //error points here at opening <
        <Link to="app">Home</Link>
        <Link to="login">Login</Link>

        <RouteHandler/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var routes = (  
  <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
    <Route name="login" path="/login" handler={LoginHandler}/>
  </Route>
);

Router.run(routes, function (Handler) {  
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
});
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "foobar",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "application foobar",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
  "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot --progress --colors",
  "build": "webpack --progress --colors",
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"author": "Justin Kruse",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.3.26",
  "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
  "history": "^1.17.0",
  "react": "^0.14.3",
  "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
  "react-router": "^1.0.3",
  "webpack": "^1.12.9",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
},
"dependencies": {
  "history": "1.17.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');  
module.exports = {  
  entry: [
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    "./js/app.js"
  ],
  output: {
      path: __dirname + '/build',
      filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
      loaders: [
          { test: /\.js?$/, loader: 'babel', exclude: /node_modules/,
              query:
                {
                  presets:['react','es2015']
                } 
          },
          { test: /\.js?$/,loaders:['react-hot'], exclude: /node_modules/},
          { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'},
          { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" }
      ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ]
};
```

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34316456/unexpected-token-error-when-npm-start-react-webpack#_=_), but it seems to be dead.

Comment: this was said before in the other question, but this tutorial is incorrect for those package versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are processing all your `.js` files through `babel` twice. One using the `react` presets:

```
 { test: /\.js?$/, loader: 'babel', exclude: /node_modules/,
     query:
       {
         presets:['react','es2015']
       } 
 },
```

And the other one without:

```
{ test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'},
```

The latter is the one that is probably giving you the error because this loader is unable to understand JSX. Just remove it.

BTW: I would take a look at [react-hot-boilerplate](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate) if you want to play with react hot module reloading.

You'll need something like this. But again, check the link above for more detailed configuration.

### webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');  
module.exports = {  
  entry: [
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    "./js/app.js"
  ],
  output: {
      path: __dirname + '/build',
      filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
      loaders: [
          { test: /\.js?$/,loaders:['react-hot', 'babel'], exclude: /node_modules/},
          { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" }
      ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ]
};
```

### .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

As a side note. Things go fast in JavaScript... Just to inform that [react-hot-loader](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader) is about to be deprecated in favor of [react-transform](https://github.com/gaearon/react-transform-boilerplate).